# How to check if SD/USB card become corrupted?

Tags: usb, filesystems, hardware-failure, sd-card

I have some raspberryPi2 model-B boards, using USB drives as their root filesystem. As it turned out, the USB chips I had chosen are prone to build up tremendous heat, and after 6-8 months, they started malfunctioning.

As far as I know, whenever a removable media becomes corrupted (or shows signs it's going to be), the memory controller disables all writes on the disk to prevent any further data corruption. This write-protection cannot be removed by conventional tools (needs manufacturer's special utilities which aren't public).

This happened to me a few times before, but I was able to migrate the whole system to the backup-USB (on the fly) when I discovered the problem in time. Sometimes however, I noticed the problem when it was too late, for eg. the system couldn't get up after reboot.

I need a proper method to check if the filesystem becomes corrupted/read-only (**by hardware failure**), so I can set up a mechanism to send notification about the problem.

I'm thinking about simply creating a test file in the temp area, and examining the command's return value, but I'm not sure it's entirely correct way to do that.

Something like this:

```
touch /tmp/testfile && { rm /temp/testfile; do stuff }
```

**TL;DR;** So basically, is there any failproof way to check the root filesystems' write permission/physical health, or this will be more than enough?

Comment: This fantasy seems to have nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: @Milliways I approve that the question was not too much Pi-related, but most linux boxes aren't using USB drives as their root partition, which is the case in my situation. So i tought it will be appropriate to ask this question on it's dedicated Stack community.

----

Out of couriosity, what do you like to tell me when using the term "fantasy"? Please pardon me, english is not my first language.

Comment: "whenever a removable media becomes corrupted (or shows signs it's going to be), the system disables all writes on the disk "

Comment: @Milliways I saw a few hints here and there on Stack Exchange, and I can remember there was an answer which linked a detailed article about the topic, but I can't find that particular answer.
---
Otherways, here's one comment that mentions this behaviour:

[Cannot format USB flash drive, everything claims it's write protected](http://superuser.com/a/819037/197567)